# Equivalence proofs concerning matrices and systems of linear equations

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbf A$ be the augmented $m × (n + 1)$ matrix of a system of $m$ linear equations
with $n$ unknowns. 
Let $\mathbf B$  be the $m × n$ matrix obtained from $\mathbf A$ by removing the last
column. 
Let $\mathbf C$ be the matrix in row reduced form obtained from $\mathbf A$ by elementary
row operations.

Prove that the following four statements are equivalent.
(i) The linear equations have no solutions.
(ii) If $c_1,\ldots, c_{n+1}$ are the columns of $\mathbf A$, then $c_{n+1}$ is not a linear combination of $c_1,\ldots, c_{n+1}$.
(iii) $Rank(\mathbf A) \gt Rank(\mathbf B)$.
(iv) The lowest non-zero row of $\mathbf C$ is $(0 0 · · · 0 0 1)$.

My aim is to prove that (i)$\Leftrightarrow$(ii), (ii)$\Leftrightarrow$(iii) and (iii)$\Leftrightarrow$(iv).
I am really struggling.  Could I have guidance as to an effective way to approach these proofs?

Comment: You may prove that (i)$\Rightarrow$(ii)$\Rightarrow$(iii)$\Rightarrow$(iv)$\Rightarrow$(i).

Comment: I've tried to show the first implication ((i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)), but I have not made any progress.  Could I have a guiding hint?

Comment: Prove that by contradiction. If (ii) is not true, that is, ${c_{n + 1}}$ is a linear combination of ${c_1}, \cdots ,{c_n}$ or ${c_{n + 1}} = {k_1}{c_1} +  \cdots  + {k_n}{c_n}$. Then rewrite the equation above in matrix form we see that ${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{k_1}}& \cdots &{{k_n}}
\end{array}} \right]^T}$ is a solution of the linear equations.

Comment: Could somebody suggest an effective way of proving (iii) $\Leftrightarrow$ (iv), please?

Comment: I have managed to prove (iii) $\Leftrightarrow$ (iv) now.

Comment: How did you show (iii)⇒(iv) ? I have no idea.

Comment: Let $\mathbf B'$ be the row reduced form (RRF) of $\mathbf B$.  Since $Rank(\mathbf C) = Rank(\mathbf A)$, $Rank(\mathbf B') = Rank(\mathbf B)$ and $Rank(\mathbf A)\gt Rank(\mathbf B)$, it follows that $Rank(\mathbf C)\gt Rank(\mathbf B')$.  Notice that $\mathbf C$ is obtained from $\mathbf B'$ by appending to $\mathbf B'$ the RRF of $c_{n+1}$.  (Recall: $Rank(\mathbf C)\gt Rank(\mathbf B')$ means that $\mathbf C$ has more non-zero rows than $\mathbf B'$.)  The only way that $\mathbf C$ can have more non-zero rows than $\mathbf B'$ is if the lowest non-zero row of C is $(0, 0,\ldots, 0, 1)$.